# how to get all tables and Their's columns of a specific schema using Java?

Tags: java, database

I have a database schema that its name is "Navid"
there is many tables in this schema.
definitely each table, has some columns.

what I need is a java class that:

1. Connect to my database.
2. Have a method that loop on all tables

   2-1. Have an inner loop to define all columns of the table.
3. Make create table query statement .(I want to create the same table in another database).
4. Execute that query.

I write some code but I do not know what to do next.

```
public class automateExport {

static String value;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // ResultSet rs = null;
    String table_name;
    String column_name;
    String tableName = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);

    Connection DB2 = getConnection();
    String sql = "SELECT TABSCHEMA,TABNAME,COLNAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE      'SYS%'";
    PreparedStatement mainStmt = DB2.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = mainStmt.executeQuery();

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    /*  while(rs.next()){
     table_name = rs.getString(2);

     // for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i ++){ 
     column_name = rs.getString(3);
     System.out.println("SSS::::: " + table_name + " " + column_name );
     // }

     */
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            table_name = rs.getString(2);
            if (i > 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }

            column_name = rs.getString(3);

            String columnType = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i);
          sb.append(" ").append(column_name).append(" ").append(columnType);

            int precision = rsmd.getPrecision(i);
            if (precision != 0) {
                sb.append("( ").append(precision).append(" )");
            }
        } // for columns
        sb.append(" ) ");


    String sql2 = sb.toString();
    PreparedStatement m = DB2.prepareStatement(sql);
    m.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }

 }

 private static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver");
    Connection connection
            = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/navid", "navid", "oracle");
    return connection;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "next"? Do you get an error? Where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: I do not know if I write a correct code or not? I want someone help me write Java class that do things I wrote above.